# Rails 5 set current_user from external API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-5

I use temporarily Rails as frontend app to communicate with an API.

After the authentication, I set the `user_id` in a cookie.
I use the `her` gem to call the User from the API and save it into an instance variable.

The issue is that I do this request on every page I and would like to do it once.
It's like @current_user is reset after each page.

```
def current_user
  #User.find -> Her model
  @current_user ||= User.find(cookies.signed[:user_id]) if cookies.signed[:user_id]
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is helpful, but all of your instance variables will be reset between requests. If you want it to be set at the beginning of every request, you can use a `before_action` callback that sets the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There no clear solution because your user coming from API. You can try to do something like that:

```
#remember user attributes without references
session['user'] = @current_user.attributes #remember
@user = OpenStruct(session['user']) #load, allow call @user.name etc, but not @user.posts

#use class variable
class User
  include Her::Model
  @@tmp = {}

  def remember
    @@tmp[id] = self
    #call job etc to delete user from tmp to prevent something that reminds "memory leak" 
  end

  def self.local_find(id)
    @@tmp[id]
  end
end

def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.local_find(cookies.signed[:user_id]) || 
    User.find(cookies.signed[:user_id]) if cookies.signed[:user_id]
end
```

**The main reason not to store(remember) objects in the session(long-term variable) is that if the object structure changes, you will get an exception.**